# Typesafe Activator running error (Could not retrieve jansi 1.11)

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I installed Typesafe Activator on Windows 8 for using Play Framework 2.3. When i'm trying to run Activator, it stops with next errors:

```
unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
 (see C:\Users\Adlaran\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve jansi 1.11
```

I don't use proxy on my computer, so [solution](https://typesafe.com/activator/docs) with proxy settings isn't suitable.

I tried to download jansi.jar from [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11), but I don't understand where it should be placed to make Activator works.

I will be grateful, if anybody write how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to put the jar here:

```
C:\Users\yourusername\.sbt\boot\other\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11
```

Did you download the minimal activator or the bundled one?

I always download the minimal, place it somewhere and then let it run to download its own stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I tried to run both of them, but they ended up with same error. Now I can use it.

Comment: Thanks! The solution works great. Wish I could upvote you multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with the unresolved dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

I was using JDK7, so I updated to JDK8 since their site says to use Java 8.  That solved the problem for me.