# org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: when running SBT in Windows command line & in IntelliJ tool

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-plugin, jansi

I am trying to use IntelliJ on a Windows 10 machine for Scala/SBT development. However I am receiving the below error every time I open a project with Scala/SBT:

```
 Error while importing sbt project: Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi
 1.11 ... :: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :: UNRESOLVED
 DEPENDENCIES :: :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::
 org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: several problems occurred while
 resolving dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
 {default=[default(compile)]}: java.util.NoSuchElementException
 java.util.NoSuchElementException java.util.NoSuchElementException
 java.util.NoSuchElementException java.util.NoSuchElementException
 :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG
 MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS unresolved dependency:
 org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: several problems occurred while
 resolving dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
 {default=[default(compile)]}: java.util.NoSuchElementException
 java.util.NoSuchElementException java.util.NoSuchElementException
 java.util.NoSuchElementException java.util.NoSuchElementException
 Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries (see
 C:\Users\kwn917\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log) Error: Could
 not retrieve jansi 1.11 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring
 option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
```

I have the "2017.3.4 Ultimate Version" of IntelliJ and have downloaded the Plugins for SBT and Scala in the Settings option.

I have also tried to run the SBT command from the windows command prompt and get the same error below:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0 Getting
org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11  (this may take some time)...

:: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS
                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
{default=[default(compile)]}:
        java.util.NoSuchElementException
        java.util.NoSuchElementException
        java.util.NoSuchElementException
        java.util.NoSuchElementException
        java.util.NoSuchElementException

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS unresolved
dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: several problems occurred
while resolving dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
{default=[default(compile)]}:
        java.util.NoSuchElementException
        java.util.NoSuchElementException
        java.util.NoSuchElementException
        java.util.NoSuchElementException
        java.util.NoSuchElementException Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries   (see
C:\Users\kwn917\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log) Error: Could
not retrieve jansi 1.11
```

I have set a SCALA_HOME, SBT_HOME, JAVA_HOME and also added them to PATH, on the system environment variables, but this has made no difference.

When I go into the Jansi file folder within the IntelliJ install the version of folder there is 1.14 (C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2\plugins\gradle\lib), but below and in the UI & when running from command line it is looking for 1.11?

Any ideas as to what the issue is here please?

Comment: Note that you don't need SBT plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA. This functionality is already included into the Scala plug-in. Check also this threads https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140202/2000323 https://stackoverflow.com/q/44143363/2000323

Comment: Yes, I get the same issue from IntelliJ using their plugins. They requested the manual install and once the issue was from command line as well, there was no further interest, as it was deemed a non IntelliJ issue.